# Unable to load client certificate private key file

Tags: meteor, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate

I am unable to create Apple Push Notification cert files. When I test .pem files I get an error.

`openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert pushapp_cert_dev.pem -key pushapp_key_dev.pem`

will give an error:

`unable to load client certificate private key file
140735327015760:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY`

I am following these instructions: https://github.com/raix/push/wiki/iOS-Micro-Walkthrough

**pushapp_cert_dev.pem**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFiTCCBHGgAw...ff6eVQDZV4=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

**pushapp_key_dev.pem**

```
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: pushApp
    localKeyID: EB 91 B3 CD A0 F5 9A 56 46 96 43 24 C8 B0 A7 56 62 01 9E 2C 
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
```

Both files are in the same location.

Comment: does your `push_key_dev` contain a section similar to `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`?

Comment: @Akshat, nope. This is the whole content of pushapp_key_dev.pem file

`Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: pushApp
    localKeyID: EB 91 B3 CD A0 F5 9A 56 46 96 43 24 C8 B0 A7 56 62 01 9E 2C 
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>`

Comment: It looks like this key didn't convert properly from p12, if that's all thats in it its missing a lot of stuff.

Comment: This is the command I used to create pushapp_key_dev.pem file `openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out pushapp_key_dev.pem -in pushapp_key_dev.p12` I just followed the instructions above.

Comment: I got it. When I created .pem file, I was asked to enter passphrase but I  didn't. Apparently min 4 char passphrase is required. However I got another error when I try to verify .pem files. `Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)`

Answer (score 2):

When I created the .pem file, I simply needed to enter passphrase (min 4 char) when prompted. First, I just skipped it because I didn't want to create passphrase. It doesn't give any error or otherwise inform that passphrase is required and it actually creates a non working .pem file.